# CLIPS weird behaviour

Tags: dialog, bind, clips

I don't understand why this binding expression is being interpreted fine on dialog but not inside a defrule:

```
CLIPS> (bind ?test (nth$ 1 (create$ 1)))

1
```

New window:

```
(defrule testrule
    (bind ?test2 (nth$ 1 (create$ 1)))
=>
    (assert (nothing here)))
```

Output after the untitled window's "Load Buffer":

```
CLIPS> Loading Selection...
Defining defrule: testrule 
[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for defrule.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::testrule
(bind ?test2 (
CLIPS>
```

How can it even fail being the same on both cases?

I have tested this problem several times, so to clarify it isn't problem from rest of defrule syntax, which you can verify by looking the defrule parsing cuts on the binding line.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with your defrule syntax. You use the test conditional element to evaluate an expression in the conditions of a rule. The syntax you've used indicates that you're attempting to match a fact with the relation name bind. The analog to what you're doing at the command line is to execute the function call to bind from the actions of the rule:

```
CLIPS> (bind ?test (nth$ 1 (create$ 1)))
1
CLIPS> 
(defrule testrule
   =>
   (bind ?test (nth$ 1 (create$ 1)))
   (printout t ?test crlf))
CLIPS> (run)
1
CLIPS>
```

Because parentheses are extensively used as delimiters in CLIPS, there are many cases where context determines the meaning of a piece of code. For example, here's a call to the printout command from the command prompt:

```
CLIPS> (printout t Hello crlf)
Hello
CLIPS>
```

Here's a similar call from the actions of a rule:

```
CLIPS> 
(defrule hello
   =>
   (printout t Hello crlf))
CLIPS> (run)
Hello
CLIPS>
```

Moving the printout code to the conditions of the rule changes the meaning of the code from a function call to a pattern intended to match a fact:

```
CLIPS> 
(defrule hello
   (printout t Hello crlf)
   =>)
CLIPS> (agenda)
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
For a total of 1 fact.
CLIPS> (assert (printout t Hello crlf))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      hello: f-1
For a total of 1 activation.
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (printout t Hello crlf)
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS>
```

The test conditional element can be used in the conditions of a rule to indicate that the enclosed code is a function call and not a pattern matching a fact:

```
CLIPS> 
(defrule hello (test (printout t Hello crlf)) =>)
Hello
CLIPS>
```

Some rule-based languages allow you to bind a variable to a derived value in the conditions of a rule, however, CLIPS does not support this, so can't get around this limitation by placing the bind functional call within a test conditional element:

```
CLIPS> (defrule hello (test (bind ?x 1)) => (printout t ?x crlf))

[PRCCODE3] Undefined variable x referenced in RHS of defrule.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::hello
   (test (bind ?x 1))
   =>
   (printout t ?x crlf))
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I don't understand how it isn't possible to assign a bind like that on the left-side and, in relation with this problem, why a simpler bind like (bind ?test 1) would work instead...

Comment: Added some additional clarification.

Comment: Seems to make sense now to me, so if I understand it fine, everything on left-side except test is only interpreted for pattern-matching, and standard functions like nth$ / create$ / etc. on a binding will fail since they can't be used on that context.

Comment: Correct. The : operator can also be used in a pattern to evaluate a function call. For example, the pattern (number ?n&:(> ?n 5)) will match all number facts having a single value that is greater than 5.